# MP3 RIPOFF problems

Tags: mp3

I am using RIPOFF to rip CD's and convert the files to MP3. The problem is that it is putting the files into the HOME FOLDER, rather than the MUSIC folder. This is risky as I accidentally lost a whole lot of system files! How do I change this please. H E L P !
Can I open a terminal to do that? I don't know how to open a terninal even...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the RipOFF Preferences you can set the Output Folder where your files will be stored, defaults to your home folder but it can be changed by simply clicking the "Save" button and choosing the new destination folder as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

You can gain access to the Preferences window by pressing Ctrl+P when in the RippOFF Application.

Good luck!